# why is default ssl certificate not working for azure web app

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I have a customer who has two web apps with exactly the same configuration and custom domains configured and SSL certs binding is complete. Ex - qa.com and prod.com. When accessing https://qa.com and https://qa.azurewebsites.net both are working fine without any certificate error. But while accessing https://prod.azurewebsites.net we are seeing below cert warning. https://prod.com is working fine. Can someone explain why the default SSL is not working for prod.azurewebsites.net

> This server could not prove that it is prod.azurewebsites.net; its
>   security certificate is from prod.com. This may be caused by a
>   misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.

Answer (score 1):

I tried browsing https://prod.azurewebsites.net/ and I am seeing the Azure landing page with *.azurewebsites.net certificate. When I browse https://prod.com/ I am getting error that site cannot be reached. Have we configured the A record and CNAME mapping for custom domain and uploaded the SSL certificate.
You can follow the steps mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain) for mapping the custom domain. For uploading the SSL certificate please refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-purchase-ssl-web-site) article.

Comment: Once the custom domains are configured will accessing *.azurewebsites.net over https throw certificate errors?

Comment: No, it should not. If you browse <webapp>.azurewebsites.net then *.azurewebsites.net certificate will be presented. If you browse the custom domain then the certificate issued to the domain will be presented. Also please check if you have any rewrite rules in web.config to redirect the azurewebsites.net domain to the custom domain.

Comment: Yes but in our case, when we access *.azurewebsites.net in browser we are seeing custom domain cert is being presented (prod.com) and we are seeing a cert error. I'm not sure why the custom domain cert is being presented.

Comment: Can you please put the configurations for custom domain so that I can reproduce the issue at my side and verify the configurations?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it was the case for you, but it took me a while to figure it out in my solution, so I thought to share this here as well, in case any one else can be helped with it.

In my case, I had a redirect configured in my application to always use www (in .NET core: `app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().AddRedirectToWwwPermanent());`).  That works perfectly for my custom domain, but that does not work together with the app.azurewebsites.net, as it redirected to [www.app.azurewebsites.net](http://www.app.azurewebsites.net).

(for reference only)